# Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have this model:

```
public class ContentType
{
    public int ContentTypeId{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public Lang Lang{get;set;}
    public bool IsPublished{get;set;}
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ContentType Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ContentType> Children { get; set; }
}
```

It has a one to many relation to itself.

And in Context I have this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ContentType>().HasMany(c => c.Children).WithOptional(c => c.Parent).HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();    
}
```

But when I am saving a record with `ParentId=0` I see this error:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.
>   Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model
>   requirements, or store-generated values.

Note that the relation in database is not exist because of the following error:

> 'ContentType' table
>   - Unable to create relationship 'FK_ContentType_ContentType'.   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE
>   constraint "FK_ContentType_ContentType". The conflict occurred in
>   database "CMS", table "dbo.ContentType", column 'ContentTypeId'.

But I don't think the problem be from here.I don't know.

What is it wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that both errors are caused by the incorrect data in the table `ContentType`.

> 'ContentType' table - Unable to create relationship
>   'FK_ContentType_ContentType'. The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted
>   with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint
>   "FK_ContentType_ContentType". The conflict occurred in database "CMS",
>   table "dbo.ContentType", column 'ContentTypeId'.

This points to the incorrect value in `ParentId` field. Verify that values in this field are in fact correct `ContentTypeId` in other records.

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.
>   Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model
>   requirements, or store-generated values.

This error points to a circular dependency. Verify that you do not have cycles in your data.

Comment: It is supposed that when a content type doesn't have a parent,the parentId field be 0. From your answer I think I should set the parent id for the root content types to null.right?

Comment: @HamidReza, absolutely. 0 is an integer, so DB treats it as a valid ID. Moreover your `ParentId` field is nullable, so I guess you where bearing the same design in mind when creating it.